# Javascript .ClientController Expando no longer available in ReportViewer using SSRS 2010?

Tags: reporting-services

We are upgrading some reports from SSRS ReportServer2005 to the latest version ReportServer2010. Not the easiest upgrade as methods names etc have changed. One remaining issue that we have is that the asp.net ReportViewer Control does not have the .ClientController Expando object and its associated methods. Is this no longer available on this version or is there something more that needs to be configured to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As fas as I know it was replaced with the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx) class (in the namespace [Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756410.aspx)). It's a quite a breaking change though.